# Description of partial-functions tag includes "history"

Tags: support, tag-management, tag-wikis

When randomly scrolling through tags on the tags page, this one [partial-functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/partial-functions) randomly caught my eye. I noticed its [description](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/partial-functions/info) is:

> *Questions on partial functions, **history**, usage, properties, significance for computability theory, connections to (inverse)-semi-groups and other algebraic theories.*

Should this be changed now that there's a stack exchange site for History of Math and Science? If so I wouldn't know what to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Questions on the history of mathematics are still on-topic on this site. Thus, there is no direct need to change this (although I personally would likely not *start* the list with 'history', but ultimately it likely does not change much).

To answer the question on how one could change it, these descriptions can be edited directly by "trusted users" (that is, those with 20k+ points), and other users can suggest edits, which are then reviewed; for the most part it is just like for posts (only the point-thresholds are  different).

To do this, one goes to the page of the tag and chooses "improve tag info" and starts editing.

For more drastic changes it can make sense to raise the issue beforehand here on meta or as an intermediate solution on chat. Likely the [Tagging](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3740/tagging) room is a good place to ask, maybe also [CURED](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2165/cured) or even the [Math Mods' Office](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20352/math-mods-office).